# How to disable main query?

Tags: wp-query

I don't use The Loop, because I use different queries to fetch posts (I use 3 queries instead of one).

How to disable main query for home, category and search pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial, because "home,category and search" are logically determined while main query churns through stuff. I am pretty sure I read this is possible, but that was in context of syndicating site that hadn't used posts/loop at all and scrapped it to do different stuff.

More typical approaches are:

1. Integrate custom logic into main query, by using `pre_get_posts`, `posts_*` and other relevant filters.
2. Leave main query for one of loops and implement other loops as secondary.

Comment: I will try that and report results.

Comment: _posts_request_ filter allows to replace main query.